# when i use sudo to run node, the Promise is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

when I run `node` without `sudo`, it run normally.

```
# node
> new Promise(function(){})
Promise { <pending> }
```

but if I run `node` with `sudo`, it alert me *Promise not defined*

```
# sudo node
> new Promise(function(){})
ReferenceError: Promise is not defined
    at repl:1:6
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:203:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:532:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:761:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:100:10)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1096:12)
```

why??

Comment: Did you install your promise library globally?

Comment: You probably previously installed an older version of node *as root* that normal users don't have access to. You can verify this with `sudo node -v`.

Comment: @mscdex i run `sudo node -v`, it show 0.10.40. this is a older version. but i use root to run this command, don't normal user.why?

Comment: sudo may give you a different PATH to logging in as root

Answer (score 0):

you have a older version of node.
when you run `sudo`, it will override PATH.
you only find older version of node.